# setState not setting when called from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple app which fetches some weather JSON and displays it. The user can either enter a location or they can hit a "Get lucky" button, which fetches a random city. the initial state is set in App.js

```
    this.state = {
      error: '',
      status: '',
      queryString: 'london,gb',
      queryID: '',
      queryType: 'q',
      cityData: cityData, 
      weatherData: {},
      isLoaded: false
    }
```

Next, I have my main App class, then I have a child component called that contains the form gubbins. I call it in app render as follows:

```
      <SearchForm
        queryString={this.state.queryString}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
        setQueryType={this.setQueryType}
        setQueryID={this.setQueryID}
        getWeatherData={this.getWeatherData}
      />
```

I use callback functions in there to set the query type (location or ID). An example of one of the call back functions in App.js is:

```
  setQueryType = (queryType) => {
    this.setState({
      queryType: queryType
    })
  }
```

This is called in the form JS using:

```
 props.setQueryType(e.target.attributes.query.value)
```

Now, here is the crux of the issue: the state doesn't update the first time, but DOES on the second click? In fact, other vars like queryString set in the fetch are not set until the second click.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/App.css';
import WeatherCard from './components/WeatherCard'
import Header from './components/Header'
import SearchForm from './components/SearchForm'
import cityData from './json/city.list'

const config = {
  API: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast',
  API_KEY: process.env.REACT_APP_OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY
}

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      error: '',
      status: '',
      queryString: 'london,gb',
      queryID: '',
      queryType: 'q',
      cityData: cityData, 
      weatherData: {},
      isLoaded: false
    }

    this.getWeatherData()
  }

  getWeatherData = (searchValue="london,gb") => {
    let URL
    URL = config.API + '?' + this.state.queryType + '='
    URL += this.state.queryType === 'q' ? searchValue : this.state.queryID
    URL += '&units=metric&APPID=' + config.API_KEY

    console.log(URL)

    fetch(URL)
      .then( result => result.json() )
      .then ( 
        (result) => {
          if ( result.cod === '200') {
            this.setState({ 
              status: result.cod,
              weatherData: result,
              queryString: result.city.name,
              isLoaded: true
            })
          } else {
            this.setState({
              status: result.cod,
              error: result.message,
              isLoaded: false
            })
          }
      },
      (error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: false,
          error: error
        })
      }
    )
    console.log(this.state.queryString)
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  }

  getWeatherCards = () => {
    let cards = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.weatherData.cnt; i++) {
      cards.push(
        <WeatherCard 
          key={i} 
          weatherList={this.state.weatherData.list[i]} 
        />
      )
    }
    return cards
  }

  setQueryType = (queryType) => {
    this.setState({
      queryType: queryType
    })
  }

  setQueryID = () => {
    let randomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.cityData.length)
    let randomCityID = this.state.cityData[randomID].id

    this.setState({
      queryID: randomCityID
    })
  }

  getlocationForm = () => {
    return(
      <SearchForm
        queryString={this.state.queryString}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
        setQueryType={this.setQueryType}
        setQueryID={this.setQueryID}
        getWeatherData={this.getWeatherData}
      />
    )
  }

  render = () => {
    if (this.state.status !== '200') {
      return (
        <div className='App'>
          <Header 
            status={this.state.status}
            error={this.state.error}
          />
          {this.getlocationForm()}
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div className='App'>
          {
            this.state.isLoaded && (
              <Header 
                cityName={this.state.weatherData.city.name} 
                countryName={this.state.weatherData.city.country} 
                status={this.state.status}
                error={this.state.error}
              />
            )
          }
          {this.getlocationForm()}
          {
            this.state.isLoaded && (
              <div className='weather-cards'>
                {this.getWeatherCards()}
              </div>
            )
          }
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

SearchForm.js

```
import React from 'react'

const SearchForm = (props) => {

  let handleChange = function(e) {
    props.handleChange(e)
  }

  let handleClick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    props.setQueryType(e.target.attributes.query.value)

    if (e.target.attributes.query.value === 'id') { 
      props.setQueryID()
    } 

    props.getWeatherData()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="search-form">
        <input 
          type="text" 
          id="query"
          name="query" 
          placeholder="Enter a location..."
          onChange={handleChange} 
        /> 
        <button 
          type="submit" 
          query="q" 
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
        <button 
          type="submit" 
          query="id" 
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          I'm feeling lucky...
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchForm
```

Comment: You don't know if the state will be updated when you call getWeatherData after calling setQueryType. setState is asynchronous and you do not use the callback to make sure the queryType is updated before fetching the new WeatherData.

Even though I don't think it answers your question, still be aware of that.

Comment: Actually @DimitriBosteels I'd argue I DO know the state will be updated because the fetch will either succeed or fail and update the state accordingly after the callbacks have run. Perhaps you could be a little clearer on what you think I should do?

Comment: I don't think this answers your question, but...I see that in your App constructor you are calling getWeatherData - usually you would do this in your componentDidMount method instead of your constructor. As per React documentation: "...componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request." - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: One more thing to know - your first call to getWeatherData may not have returned to set the state when you click the button. You should probably pass a property to your child while your getWeatherData method is busy so that the child form can disable the Submit button. Add a new state property isLoading. Make sure to set isLoading to true before you make your async call and set it to false when done.

Comment: @DanielMiller , what I mean is that you call your setState method, and after that you call your getWeatherData which uses the state. But the setState is asynchronous so it could run the getWeatherData with the old state. 
The setState method has a callback parameter, to ensure something runs after the setState method has been finished.
Here is what I meant

Comment: Woohhoo! You nailed it. It was the async stuff. Once I cleaned up all those functions, condensed them to one and used a callback, it worked!! Bravo :) @DimitriBosteels

Comment: @Daniel Miller , Nice ! Mind if I set my comment as an answer so you can select it? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the fact that when you call `getWeatherData`,
you don't know if the `setState` will be over as it is an asynchronous method. (as you can see in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate))

So the best way, to ensure that the `setState` is done before calling your method without being certain of the state of your component, would be to use the callBack parameter of the setState to ensure it runs after the `setState` method has been finished.

Answer (score 1):

In your `App.js` constructor add `this.setQueryType = this.setQueryType.bind(this)`

That line will bind the context of `this` to the current component, so when called from a child, will update parent state.

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped another issue I was having, but I still have to click at least twice for the state to update and the query to run properly

Answer (score 0):

try to put your this.getWeatherData() into the componentDidMount and remove it from the constructor

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.getWeatherData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this didn't solve it but is a much better approach